# balancer-manager not accessible

Tags: apache2, load-balancing

Whenever I try to access /balancer-manager in the browser, I get a 404 from the connected Tomcat cluster. Any idea what is wrong here?

Environment: Apache/2.2.10 (Linux/SUSE)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass / balancer://myalfresco-cluster/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://myalfresco-cluster/

<Proxy balancer://myalfresco-cluster>
    BalancerMember ajp://server1:8009 route=jvm1
    BalancerMember ajp://server2:8009 route=jvm2
    ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID
</Proxy>

<Location /balancer-manager>
    SetHandler balancer-manager
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Location>

<Location />
    [cluster config]
</Location>


</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be two issue.

1. You are somehow blocked by your .htaccess. 
   Check your Document Root .htaccess file. 
   Add this line "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/balancer-manager" without quote if the rewrite engine is on.
2. Another problem that I did not face but people has reported is your wild card virtual host tag. 
   Replace the wildcard with actual ip.

I felt obliged to answer this question since I wasted much time trying to find a solution to the problem and I landed on your question quite often through google but without answer.

Comment: Thanks dee, I appreciate it. I discovered that the same config works as it should in a recent Ubuntu, so this must be an issue with Suse or the slightly outdated packages it uses. Why people choose Suse over Ubuntu in this day and age is beyond me, but I'll try ditching the wildcard and see if that helps.

Comment: Flagging this as correct to appreciate the effort, since no other replies were given.

Comment: I since found out that early Apache 2.2 versions are buggy, and upgrading will resolve the issue. I have no idea which version specifically solves the bug or how to workaround it in earlier versions, though.